How to know all the dates when was accomplished all the full upgrades versions of the OS?
I have a machine with Ubuntu Desktop that was full upgraded as follows:

18:04
20:04
22:04

How would be possible to know the date when was accomplished each full upgrade? In this case for the 3 versions

Look at /var/log/apt/*. I'd make a local copy, uncompress everything, and investigate with less, grep, and other text tools. Also check sudo journalctl  --list-boots.

Duplicate of Check Ubuntu version history
